# Site search shows loading forever when input is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

**Description:**

In the **Sites** screen, if I search with an empty string, it shows the loading indicator forever.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left drawer.
2. In the **SITES** section, tap **More Sites**.
3. In the **Sites** screen, tap the text field. The keyboard shows up.
4. Tap **Search** in the keyboard.

**Actual Results:**

It shows the loading indicator forever.

**Expected Results:**

It shouldn't show a loading indicator. Perhaps it should act as if I tapped the Cancel button next to the text field.

Actually, why should there be a loading indicator in the first place? The search doesn't even require an internet connection.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.25
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot with loading indicator]

Comment: Thanks for the report. I'm looking at this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 0.1.26. The issue existed for other places where we do a search, such as question search.

Comment: Verified fixed in 0.1.26.